# Win32 - Can one Enumerate the windows belonging to the calling thread?

Tags: ruby, winapi

From MSDN on GetActiveWindow
"Retrieves the window handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue."

I'm writing SketchUp plugins using its Ruby API. Currently trying to make some tweaks to some windows via the Win32. From the Ruby API I have very limited info about SU's window and thread. GetActiveWindow works fine as long as the SketchUp window has focus - but fails otherwise.

So I am looking for a safe way to get hold of the handle to the SketchUp window regardless of whether it has focus or not.

Seeing how GetActiveWindow is able to get the active window for the calling process I was wondering if it was possible to enumerate the windows that belong to the calling process instead. Then I can scan through the results and find my window.

Alternatively, getting the process id for the calling thread, so I can enumerate ALL windows and pick out the one that belong to the thread my script runs in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find all top-level windows. In Ruby, [win32-api](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/124778) supports passing in appropriate callbacks.

Edit: You can then use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine what process each window belongs to.

Edit: To determine the process id of the process running your script, use [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that I don't have enough info to just iterate EnumWindows and filter out all the windows because there might be multiple instances of SketchUp running - so I need to find the one that belongs to the script I'm executing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been completely clear about my scenario. But the whole issue I'm having is that I'm trying to get hold of the window handle for the main window of the SketchUp process that runs my script. From the Win32API methods I've seen that get window handles or thread ids I seem to always appear to require one of them - but I have none.

Comment: @thomthom: see my edit. It's very easy to find out the process ID of the SketchUp process running your script: it will be the current process ID in your script.

Comment: Thanks. That along with GetCurrentThreadId should allow me to find my window.